# Split the Signup screen into 2 screens 1. Email validation 2. actual user registration

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking to split the Sign Up page into 2 screens as mentioned in this link; https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup

However, the Username that I am using as the UPN value in B2C isn't email address. Can someone guide me on how to get this done if the SigninName is the username instead of an email

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin).

"For scenarios where you would like users to sign up and sign in with Usernames rather than Emails".